# How to Access and change value of a variable in different modules of python?

Tags: python, variables, module, global-variables

I have a file which holds the variable

```
#config.py    
data = []
```

Two files which use a variable in the config file and append value for the same

```
#file1.py

import config as c
c.data.append("abc")

#file2.py

import config as c
c.data.append("def")
```

Finally, in the main file, I want to execute 2 files and print the value of the data

```
#main.py

import config as c
os.system("python file1.py")
os.system("python file2.py")
print(c.data)
```

expected output

```
["abc","def"]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Don't do this. Find some other way of achieving what you want

Comment: how this can achieved?